# I can't seem to link g++ to my installed libcurl

Tags: c++, curl, visual-studio-code, g++, vcpkg

I am new to programming in c++. I am trying to compile a code using curl in it. My visual studio code is able to find the file (as it autocompletes as well), but when I run "build task g++" it says the following:

```
C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Temp\cceVTTmY.o:test.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_init'
C:\Users\matth\AppData\Local\Temp\cceVTTmY.o:test.cpp:(.text+0x21): undefined reference to `_imp__curl_easy_cleanup'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I don't get it. I installed curl with vcpkge and integrated it, so visual studio code can actually find it.

I used this in my args for tasks.json for g++:

```
"args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "-I",
                "C:\\Program Files\\vcpkg-master\\installed\\x86-windows\\include",
                "-L",
                "C:\\Program Files\\vcpkg-master\\installed\\x86-windows\\lib",
                "-static"

            ],
```

I have also tried adding '-lcurl' but then the cmd actually responds saying 'cant't find lcurl'.
I am struggling for a lot of hours now (as I said, new to c++) and I am getting really frustrated.

This is the code I am trying to compile:

```
#define CURL_STATICLIB
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main()
{
    CURL *curl;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    return 0;
}
```

Anyone that knows how to fix this problem? All solutions I could find didn't work, so I decided to make my own account and try it this way...

Thanks a lot in advance, if you need more info, tell me! :)

Comment: you forget to add the curl lib to the arguments `-lcurl`

Comment: @rioV8 what do you mean? As I mentioned if I add "-lcurl" to the arguments, it says it cannot find -lcurl. Or do i have to do something different?

Comment: then you have to find the correct directory where `libcurl` is, and add this also to the argument list with `-L`

Comment: The thing is, libcurl.lib is in that directory, but still cant find it. Man libcurl is really being annoying right now hahaha.

Comment: you are using `g++` with Visual Studio libraries. That will not work. Search for `libcurl` that belongs to g++

Answer (score 1):

Problem:

There are 2 main methods of adding a C++ Library including CURL to your C++ project

Dynamic Library linking - By Including .dll file alongside your .exe)

Static Library linking - Doesn't require a .dll (it's automatically added to your .exe/bin file which will make it slightly larger but less files to maintain)

The steps below will show you the Dynamic linking method.

Environment: Windows 11+ (but may work on older systems), using Visual Studio code, and C++ compiler such as g++ there are a few tasks to perform.

1. Create your curl code as per below including the curl header such as below curl.cpp example file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>

#ifdef _WIN32
std::string curlExeFilePath = "./curl/bin/curl.exe";
#elif __APPLE__
std::string curlExeFilePath = "./curl/bin/curl.bin";
#else
std::string curlExeFilePath = "./curl/bin/curl";
#endif

const std::string curlCertPath = "./curl/bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt";

int main()
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl)
    {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com/");

        // Configure curl with curl.exe path
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PATH_AS_IS, 1L); // Set this to avoid converting slashes
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_PATH_AS_IS, curlExeFilePath.c_str());
        // Set CA cert path
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, curlCertPath.c_str());

        // this is the actual Curl command.
        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if (res == CURLE_OK)
        {
            // to test if Curl worked. If you get no output then run the program.exe with cin.get() for results.
            std::cout << "Curl worked" << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Error: curl failed: curl_easy_perform() returned error: " << curl_easy_strerror(res) << std::endl;
        }

        std::cin.get();
        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }
    curl_global_cleanup();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

2. Save as any name e.g. test.cpp in a location such as C:/documents/test_program/test.cpp
3. Download curl from the official curl website (choose the default 64 bit version): https://curl.se/windows/
4. Extract folder (and rename as "curl") in the same location as the code in test_program e.g. "C:/documents/test_program/curl
   there should then be 2 items in top directory
   "C:/documents/test_program/curl
   "C:/documents/test_program/test.cpp
5. In VScode click on "view" - "command palate" or enter keys CTRL + SHIFT + P
6. Then search and click on "tasks:configure tasks" - "Create tasks.json file from template" this will then create a tasks .json file.
7. Open your tasks.json file and in the "args" parameter enter
   /* curl files below for curling websites

   ```
            -I. = Include xxx (for headers)
            -L. = Link library directory
            -l = link library itself

             e.g.

            "-I./curl/include",
            "-L./curl/lib",
            "-lcurl",
   ```

```
{
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: g++.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
                "-I${fileDirname}",
                /* curl files below for curling websites
                -I. = Include xxx (for headers)
                -L. = Link library directory
                -l = link library itself
                */
                "-I./curl/include",
                "-L./curl/lib",
                "-lcurl"                
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ],
    "version": "2.0.0"
}
```

8. Copy over the file: curl\bin\libcurl-x64.dll besides your test.cpp file
9. Save and build.

Problems: If you're code doesn't give any output, run the .exe and see the error.

If you change the location of you're curl folder, then remember to update the source code e.g. "test.cpp" global variable file paths, and include/lib paths in your tasks.json

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck in the same problem for almost 1 month (I have certainly not been the only one, since there are plenty posts of the topic).
I am not a professional, so I will just tell you what configuration worked for me.
You have already stated that your installation of curl was successful, so let's skip that part.
In your tasks.json, inside "args": [ , you should have this lines:

```
"args":[

            "-I",
            "C:\\(path of curl you have used to installation)\\include",
            "-L",
            "C:\\(path of curl you have used to installation)\\lib",
            "-lcurl",
            "-mwindows",
            "-lgdi32",
            "-municode"
```

Besides, you must have written in your code the following sentence:

```
#define CURL_STATICLIB
```

Try this, as it is. Let me know how it was. Hope it works for you too. ;)